# How i can call one method inside another method result?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, ether, erc-20

i want to call two methods first call one method then second method after first method success below is my code please check and let me know how i can achieve this

```
this.state.token.methods.approve(this.state.neutralG.address, qty).send({ from: this.state.account}).
  then('receipt', (receipt)=>{

   this.state.neutralG.methods.createEscrow(intvalue, 3600, price, this.symbol, beneficiaryAddress, qty,
    this.tokenAddress).send({ from: this.state.account}).
  once('receipt', (receipt)=>{
    this.setState({loading: false})
  })

  })
```

this is not calling second transaction.

Comment: Is this full code ? What is the "first method" and "second method" ? Moreover, you have comment section line 2.

Comment: approve is my first method and createEscrow is my second method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your on, once and then are wrong. Please try as below:

```
this.state.token.methods.approve(this.state.neutralG.address, qty).send({ from: this.state.account})
  .on('receipt', (receipt)=>{
this.callCreateEscrow();
console.log('receipt');
  })

function callCreateEscrow(){
this.state.neutralG.methods.createEscrow(intvalue, 3600, price, this.symbol, beneficiaryAddress, qty,
    this.tokenAddress).send({ from: this.state.account})
  .on('receipt', (receipt)=>{
    this.setState({loading: false})
  })
}
```

And also please check other things in .on('<>', ).... They can be 'receipt', 'confirmation', 'transactionHash' etc.,

reference: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id22

Comment: not working only first method execute

Comment: I have edited my answer. Can you check and tell if this works. And also check if receipt is getting logged.

Comment: not working only approve call also receipt not logging

Comment: Then your approve is not returning any receipt. Can you try using 'transactionHash' instead of 'receipt' and check if it is getting a Hash or not